# bookmark package

Tags: bookmarks

I use LaTeX and want to create a bookmark which opens a file but I want to specify the page no. I have looked at `texdoc bookmark` but cannot get it to work.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean you couldn't get `texdoc` to work or you couldn't then get `bookmark` to work? Can you provide a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Key `gotor` specifies the external PDF file, `page` the page number (1-based), and `view` configures, how the page is displayed, e.g. `Fit` the whole page, with `FitH 800` the page width is showed at vertical position 800 bp from the bottom.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\bookmark[
  gotor={t.pdf},
  page=2,
  view=FitH 800,% vertical position from bottom in bp
  % view=Fit,
]{External file}
\end{document}
```